# NASM mov instruction syntax

Tags: assembly, nasm, memory-address, mov

Recently I adopted the powerful NASM as my default Assembler. Although I'm having difficulties with instruction syntax.

In TASM I think this is a valid instruction:

```
mov [dword ptr [ebp + 8]], edx
```

But how to perform the equivalent in NASM?

Also, since this is a very basic question where can I found documentation and/or examples for this type of questions?

Thanks

Comment: No, that's not a valid instruction. The x86 ISA does not have that addressing mode.

Comment: Well, then I must use two instructions for this addressing mode.

Comment: @Jester: TASM32 gives no error. It just ignores the outer pair brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In this case NASM knows the size: `mov [ebp + 8], edx`.

Another example: `inc dword [ebp + 8]`.

The NASM manual is here: http://www.nasm.us/doc/

Comment: That instruction is not equivalent.
What I desire is to update a pointer address content (mov [dword [ebp + 8]], edx).

Comment: @luiez: I tested it with Turbo Assembler 5.0 (TASM32.EXE) and NASM 2.11.06. Both produce the machine code `89 55 08`.